# global sections of a sheaf supported in points

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cohomology

I am studying torsion free sheaves on $\mathbb{P}^2$, and the following doubt appeared, if one has a torsion free sheaf $E$ on $\mathbb{P}^2$, its double dual $E^{\vee \vee}$ is a vector bundles, and furthermore,  we have the following sequence:

$0 \to E \to E^{\vee \vee} \to Q_E \to 0$

Where $Q_E$ is supported on the points where $E$ is not locally free (hence a finite number of points). My problem is that one can define the number $s_E = h^0(\mathcal{Ext^1}(E,\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}))$, and it is possible to show that $s_E = h^0(Q_E(l))$ for every $l \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Using local to global spectral sequence, and the long exat sequence of chomology one can show that $h^0(\mathcal{Ext^1}(E,\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2})) = h^0(Q_E(-3))$. But I don't understand why the dimension of the global sections of the sheaf $Q_E$ are constant for each twist. Any help will be welcome.

Comment: Because any line bundle $O_{P^2}(l)$ is trivial in a neighborhood of any zero-dimensional subscheme of $P^2$.

Comment: Thank you, so I can say that $H^0(Q_E(l)) = H^0(Q_E \otimes O_{P^2}(l)) = \sum \dim O_{P^2,p_i}/m_{p_i}$, where $p_i$ are the singular points?

Comment: $Q_E \otimes O_{P^2}(l) \cong Q_E$.